# Querying users selected Send through Office 365 settings

Tags: outlook, lightning-outlook

We would like to understand how many of our user in Salesforce chose to send email through Outlook after we turned that feature on in Production.
Has anybody found out already how to query that information?
[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I checked [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm)  of User object and there is no such field to extract email settings